# ArtistAnimation of subplots with different framerates

Tags: python, matplotlib

Consider the following code which implements `ArtistAnimation` to animate two different subplots within the same figure object.

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as ml
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def f(x,y,a):
    return ((x/a)**2+y**2)

avals = np.linspace(0.1,1,10)
xaxis = np.linspace(-2,2,9)
yaxis = np.linspace(-2,2,9)

xy = itertools.product(xaxis,yaxis)
xy = list(map(list,xy))
xy = np.array(xy)
x = xy[:,0]
y = xy[:,1]



fig, [ax1,ax2] = plt.subplots(2)

ims = []

for a in avals:
    xi = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), len(x))
    yi = np.linspace(min(y), max(y), len(y))
    zi = ml.griddata(x, y, f(x, y, a), xi, yi, interp='linear')  # turn it into grid data, this is what imshow takes
    title = plt.text(35,-4,str(a), horizontalalignment = 'center')
    im1 = ax1.imshow(zi, animated = True, vmin = 0, vmax = 400)
    im2 = ax2.imshow(zi, animated=True, vmin=0, vmax=400)
    ims.append([im1,im2, title])

ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval = 1000, blit = False)

plt.show()
```

In this case the number of items in `im1` and `im2` are the same, and the frame rate for each subplot is identical.

Now, imagine I have 2 lists with *different* numbers of items, and that I wish `ArtistAnimate` to go through the frames in the same total time. Initially I thought of manipulating the `interval` keyword in the `ArtistAnimation` call but this implies that you can set different intervals for different artists, which I don't think is possible.

Anyway, I think the basic idea is pretty clear `len(im1)` is not equal to `len(im2)`, but the animation needs to go through them all in the same amount of time.

Is there any way to do this please? Thanks

**EDIT**

While I try out the answer provided below, I should add that I would rather use `ArtistAnimation` due to the structure of my data. If there are no alternatives I will revert to the solution below.

Comment: I don't quite see in how far the data structure would make ArtistAnimation prreferable above FuncAnimation. In theory you could of course define a comon framerate and supply the same artist several times to the list, i.e. you have `ims=[[imA_1,imB_1],[imA_1,imB_2],[imA_2,imA_3],...]` (for a doubled framerate), but that using FuncAnimation is really much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is possible, kinda, using `Funcanimation` and encapsulating your data inside `func`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

arr1 = np.random.rand(300,3,4)
arr2 = np.random.rand(200,5,6)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)
img1 = ax1.imshow(arr1[0])
img2 = ax2.imshow(arr2[0])

# set relative display rates
r1 = 2 
r2 = 3

def animate(ii):
    if ii % r1:
        img1.set_data(arr1[ii/r1])
    if ii % r2:
        img2.set_data(arr2[ii/r2])
    return img1, img2

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, func=animate, frames=np.arange(0, 600))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Any way to do this using ArtistAnimation? My data is in reality more complex and I'd rather iterate through a dictionary and populate lists to get it...

Comment: `arr1` and `arr2` could equally be lists of frames. All that you pass to `animate` is an index.

Comment: Allright. I could try that. Also just fyi your code doesn't work in my version of python. I get an error `File "D:/11200999 - POVProject/Validation/Dike1/DisplayRate.py", line 18, in animate
    img1.set_data(arr1[ii/r2])
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices`